# Time for a new moderator election?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

If I read the tea leaves correctly, it appears as though one of my favorite moderators will be leaving us soon.  Another of our moderators already appears to be pretty much inactive.

Will we be electing another moderator in the near future?

Comment: Who's leaving?.

Comment: @JimG. The moderator formerly known as Enderland.

Comment: Sorry you did not get elected.

Comment: @paparazzo Thanks, its the first time I have ran for something like this.  I learned a lot, especially the lesson *you have more enemies than you think* and *the internet remembers*.

Comment: @MisterPositive I felt like some of your comments were misinterpreted.  Sites have different personalities we got the mods that match the personality of the site.  I felt like you would have mover the site in a direction I think it should go.  You notice I did not run as I have said things that have rubbed people wrong.

Comment: @paparazzo not to go to far with this here, but some of the blame falls squarely on me.  Part of it was, well, what it was.

Comment: @Neo nah, part of it was people being petty.  These people won't put themselves up for examination, but the salivate at the prospect of lining up to attack when the opportunity presents itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We have an election scheduled to start next week.  We have a week of question collection (for the questionnaire), followed by nominations.  So go ahead and start thinking about what questions you'd like candidates to answer.

We really need some level-headed, community-minded volunteers to step up and help manage the site.  I hope we will see lots of strong candidates when nominations open the week after next.

Comment: [Question Collection](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5181/2018-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) has begun